# Insert into SQLite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a tsv file containing the mapping for two kinds of identifiers.

```
accession   accession.version   taxid   gi
V00184      V00184.1            44689   7184
V00185      V00185.1            44689   7186
V00187      V00187.1            44689   7190
X07806      X07806.1            7227    8179
```

Basically, I want to be able to get the `taxid` from an `accession` number. I though I could put this in a database with a PRIMARY KEY on the `accession` field.

This is what I did and It works but I have around 1.5billion lines and it takes a lot of time to do.

```
import sqlite3
import time

start = time.time()

connection = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")
cursor = connection.cursor()    

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map (
        accession TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        accession_version TEXT,
        taxid TEXT, gi TEXT
    )""")


def read_large_file(f):
    """Generator for the file"""
    for l in f:
        yield l.strip().split()

with open("test_file.map", "r") as f:
    next(f)  # ignore header
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO map VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", read_large_file(f))

cursor.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()

print(time.time() - start)
```

Do you have any tricks or ideas I could use to speed up the insert ? (I will do very basic SELECT on the data using the `accession` primary key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some comments on your code:

- An `sqlite3` connection [can be used as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager). This ensures that the statement is committed if it succeeds and rolled back in case of an exception. Unfortunately it does not also close the connection afterwards

  ```
  with sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite") as connection, open("test_file.map") as f:
      connection.execute("""
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map (
              accession TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
              accession_version TEXT,
              taxid TEXT, gi TEXT
          )""")

      next(f)  # ignore header
      connection.executemany("INSERT INTO map VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", read_large_file(f))
  connection.close()
  ```
- You should separate your functions from the code calling it. The general layout for Python code is to first define your classes, then your functions and finally have a main block that is protected by a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from the script without executing all the code.
- `open` automatically opens a file in read-mode, if not specified otherwise.

---

That being said, if you have a billion lines, basically any approach is probably going to be slow. Here is an alternate approach using [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/). It may or may not be faster, you will have to test it. The usage is very similar to `pandas`, except that the computations are only performed once committed to with the call to `compute()`.

First, to install `dask`:

```
pip install dask[dataframe] --upgrade
```

Then for the actual usecase you mention, finding a specific `gi` in the table:

```
from dask import dataframe

df = dataframe.read_csv("test_file.map", sep="\t")
df[df.gi == 7184].compute()
#   accession accession.version  taxid    gi
# 0    V00184          V00184.1  44689  7184
```

In the call to `dataframe.read_csv` you can set it to [read the file in blocks](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) if needed, e.g. in 25MB chunks:

```
df = dataframe.read_csv("test_file.map", sep="\t", blocksize=25e6)
```

Comment: Thank you !
I've tried dask and it wasn't faster for this particular case but It seems like I could use it somewhere else.

Something I noticed is the PRIMARY KEY statement, removing it seemed to speed up the insertion. However SQLite3 does not provide an `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` functionality. I'm trying with Postgresql to see if adding the constraint afterwards leads to any significant improvements